# Avoid reimporting data to a map as more data gets added to the folder

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, import

I created a script to add TIFF files to a map so I don't have to manually add them. I have been able to have multiple files uploaded at once but in doing so, I duplicate multiple files that are already on the map. There are constantly files being added and I only want to add the new ones as an "update". How do I prevent duplication? My code is below:

```
# Path to the ArcGIS Pro project
project_path = r"path"

# Folder containing the TIF files
tif_folder = r"path"

# Set var as your current project
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(project_path)

# Get the map from the project 
map = aprx.listMaps(map_name)[0]  

for file in os.listdir(tif_folder):
    if file[-4:] == '.tif':
        filepath = tif_folder + '\\' + file
        map.addDataFromPath(filepath)
```

Comment: Look at [`map.listLayers`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm).

Comment: Compare the name of the TIFF file (basename, without the ".tif" extension) with all of the existing layers in the map.  If a layer with the same name already exists, then skip that TIFF file.  IF you want to get more fancy, then check the existing layer's type first to see if it is a raster, or you could even check the data source of the existing layer to see if it is a TIFF file in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the name of each TIFF file (basename, without the ".tif" extension) with all of the existing layers in the map. If a layer with the same name already exists, then skip that TIFF file.  See a possible method in the script below (untested!)

You could go further by also checking if the existing layer is a raster, or you could even check the data source of the existing layer to see if it is a TIFF file in that folder.

```
# Path to the ArcGIS Pro project
project_path = r"path"

# Folder containing the TIF files
tif_folder = r"path"

# Set var as your current project
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(project_path)

# Get the map from the project 
map = aprx.listMaps(map_name)[0]  

#  Get names of all existing layers as a list of strings
existingLayerNames = [l.name for l in map.listLayers()]
print(existingLayerNames)

for file in os.listdir(tif_folder):
    fName, fExt = os.path.splitext(file)
    if fExt != '.tif' or fName in existingLayerNames:
        #  Skip this file and continue to the next one
        continue
    filepath = os.path.join(tif_folder, file)
    map.addDataFromPath(filepath)
    print(fName)
```

Note that I've made a few other changes to 'tidy up' the script (in my opinion):

- different method of creating the path for the `filepath` variable, which I think is a safer technique to use
- different method of getting the file extension (which simultaneously also gets the file name so that it can be compared with the layer names)
- the `if` statement now checks the extension AND the existence of a layer with the same name all within the one `if`
- the `if` statement now skips the code within the `for` loop, rather than executing that code (`continue` skips to the next `for` iteration)

Comment: This looks exactly what I am looking for! Just for clarification as a newbie, could you explain the `[l.name for l in map.listLayers()]`? I understand what the intent is but don't understand exactly what is going on?  Is it iterating through the existing layers. The l.name portion confuses me.

Comment: The script runs but it is still duplicating. any thoughts?

Comment: `[l.name for l in map.listLayers()]` is a Python "list comprehension" (see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp ).  It is generating a list of all the layer names.  The `l` is the layer object for each layer in `map.listLayers()` and `l.name` is the `name` property of that layer.

Comment: Still duplicating?  That implies some issue with comparing the layer names to the file names, perhaps.  After the `existingLayerNames = ...` line, add a line, `print(existingLayerNames)`.  Then after the `map.addDataFromPath()` line at the end, add a line, `print(fName)`.  (I've added these to the script in this answer now, too).  What output do you get?

Comment: I figured it out. I need to add the fExt to the fName for it to register since the layers had the extension in it. So now it looks like this:
for file in os.listdir(tif_folder):
    `fName, fExt = os.path.splitext(file)
    if fExt != '.tif' or fName + fExt in existinglayernames:
        #  Skip this file and continue to the next one
        continue`

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I appreciate your time.